# (Firebase) Foto de usuario logeado con cuenta de google no carga ¿Que debo hacer?

Tags: firebase

Estoy viendo el tema de autenticacion de usuarios con firebase. Estoy autenticando usuarios mediante la cuenta de google que ellos tienen.

La foto de perfil no me carga. Estoy usando un servidor local para hacer las pruebas

```
function getStateAuth(user) {
    if (user) {
        Logeado.innerHTML = `Bienvenido: ${user.displayName} <img src=${user.photoURL}/>`
    } else {
        Logeado.innerHTML = "Inicia sesion porfavor "
    }
}
```

Esa funcion es un callback, que paso como argumento a `onAuthStateChanged`

Intente cargar la foto en una ventana del navegador y obtengo un error 404. Esta es la url que comente anteriormente:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gh_hA7cFqNeqQ5TFLwyHVtCQPDoHwjS5_QO8Yis/

¿Alguien sabe porque sucede esto?

Answer (score 0):

El problema de la URL es la `/` del final

Si cambias

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gh_hA7cFqNeqQ5TFLwyHVtCQPDoHwjS5_QO8Yis/
```

por

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gh_hA7cFqNeqQ5TFLwyHVtCQPDoHwjS5_QO8Yis
```

La URL funciona

El problema está en que estas agregando la `/` al final de la URL

```
<img src=${user.photoURL}/>`
```

Podes solucionarlo de la siguiente forma

```
<img src=${user.photoURL}></img>
```